# Problem with subcaption spacing

Tags: spacing, captions, positioning, subfloats, subcaption

When using the `subcaption` package to place tables<sup>1</sup> side-by-side, the spacing between a table and its subtable caption is too small if the table caption is placed *above* the tables and the subtable captions are placed *below* the tables, as shown in the following example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,subcaption}

\newcommand\exampletable{
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    A & B\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

1) This looks OK:

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \centering
    \exampletable
    \caption{Subcaption 1}
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \centering
    \exampletable
    \caption{Subcaption 2}
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{Main caption}
\end{table}

2) And this looks OK:

\begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{Main caption}
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \caption{Subcaption 1}
    \centering
    \exampletable
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \caption{Subcaption 2}
    \centering
    \exampletable
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}

3) Even this looks OK:

\begin{table}[!h]
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \caption{Subcaption 1}
    \centering
    \exampletable
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \caption{Subcaption 2}
    \centering
    \exampletable
  \end{subtable}
  \caption{Main caption}
\end{table}

4) But in this case, the spacing isn't nice:

\begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{Main caption}
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \centering
    \exampletable
    \caption{Subcaption 1}
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \centering
    \exampletable
    \caption{Subcaption 2}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This produces something that looks like this:

[image: Table 4 has too little spacing between tables and subtable captions]

Table 4 is the problematic case. I would prefer it to look more like this instead:

[image: This is what table 4 should look like]

Any ideas on how to fix this? Ideally, I would want to have the right spacing "automagically" without having to insert explicit vspaces or anything similar inside the subtable environments.

<sub>1: the same would apply to figures, or other kinds of subfloats.</sub>

Comment: You really should decide for one position and be consistent. If you want to have the subcaptions below, tell the package about it: `\captionsetup[subtable]{position=below}`.

Comment: @johannes-b: I totally agree with that. However, I face this problem as part of trying to create a customized document class, and I want the guys using the class to have the freedom of choosing their layout themselves.

It kind of surprises me that \captionsetup[subtable]{position=below} actually fixes the problem for the case with Table 4. So it seems almost like the main caption of the table environment overrides the position attribute of the subtable environment, or something.

Comment: No problem, let the user decide where the captions should go. It is no secret that LaTeX doesn't know, if the space belongs on top or after a caption. Thats where package `caption` comes in.

Comment: @Johannes_B: I guess you're absolutely right - after all, this is what it says in the caption manual §3.6 (after I just read it a bit more carefully). What puzzles me, however, is that if you add something like `\captionsetup[subtable]{skip=20pt}` to my example, LaTeX actually seems to figure out the correct place to put the spacing in all cases (even for Table 3) except for Table 4. Also interestingly, if one comments out the `\caption{Main caption}` in Table 4, the subtable captions are spaced out correctly.

Comment: Read a bit further till you get to `postition=auto`, i guess this is going on here.

Comment: @Johannes_B: Actually, invoking `\captionsetup[subtable]{position=auto}` globally results in proper spacing (the way I wanted it) in all four cases :)

Comment: You can provide a self answer and share the solution with others ;-) Accompanied with some explanations, this makes a good answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

After [Johannes_b](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/231512/problem-with-subcaption-spacing?noredirect=1#comment547685_231512) pointed me in the right direction, it turned out that using `\captionsetup[subtable]{position=auto}` fixes the spacing in all four cases.

## Long answer

After some experimentation, it seemed to me that the `\caption` of the outer `table` environment somehow affected the `\caption` used in the inner `subtable` environment. This led med to attempt wrapping the table `\caption` in a `\begingroup`-`\endgroup` pair to isolate any side-effects. In the following MWE, this was done with the problematic case 4:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,subcaption,blindtext}
\captionsetup[subtable]{skip=20pt}

\newcommand\exampletable{
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
    \toprule
    A & B\\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}

A single line of text that shows the spacing between the text and the float.

\begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{Main caption}
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \centering
    \exampletable
    \caption{Subcaption 1}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}

A single line of text that shows the spacing between the text and the float.

\begin{table}[!h]
  \begingroup
  \caption{Main caption}
  \endgroup
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \centering
    \exampletable
    \caption{Subcaption 1}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}

A single line of text that shows the spacing between the text and the float.

\end{document}
```

And the result confirms the suspicion:

[image: Isolating caption in group]

Table 2 in the image above corresponds to the case where `\caption` was used within a group.

After some digging through the `caption` source code, it turns out that the `\caption@position` macro is set as a result of using `\caption` in the `table` environment (it is undefined initially, unless overridden globally), and it is tested for with the `\caption@iftop` macro when `\caption` is used again in the `subtable` environment. In other words, the position attribute of the caption in the outer environment will override the caption position in nested environments, if their `\caption` commands succeed the `\caption` command of the outer environment, and the caption positions of the nested environments haven't been set explicitly.

To confirm this, I tried to reset the value of `\caption@position` after the table caption:

```
\begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{Main caption}
  \makeatletter
  \let\caption@position\@undefined
  \makeatother
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \centering
    \exampletable
    \caption{Subcaption 1}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}
```

and it turned out that this had the same effect as wrapping the `\caption` in a group.

Note that the code above should *not* be used as a solution to this problem! Even the caption package source code states that the `\caption@position` macro should not be depended on.

### So why does position=auto work?

It turns out that using `\captionsetup[subtable]{position=auto}` will result in a call to `\caption@setposition{auto}` before the subtable caption is output, and the `auto` argument will simply do `\let\caption@position\@undefined`, which is exactly what we wanted.

Comment: What a good self-answer! Keep it up! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Although I agree with the above comment, the problem seems to come with the interaction of the bottomrule and the subcaption. Indeed, as shown below, there is no spacing problem with a something not involving rules. A dirty trick is to replace the bottomrule provided by `booktabs` with a `specialrule` in which the spacing below it is increased.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs,caption,subcaption}
\newcommand\exampletableA{
\LARGE A
}
\newcommand\exampletable{
  \begin{tabular}{ll}
  \toprule
    A & B\\\specialrule{\heavyrulewidth}{\aboverulesep}{2\belowrulesep}
  \end{tabular}
}
\captionsetup{skip=10pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{Main caption}
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \centering
    \exampletableA
    \caption{Subcaption 1}
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \centering
    \exampletableA
    \caption{Subcaption 2}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}

\begin{table}[!h]
  \caption{Main caption}
  \centering
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \centering
    \exampletable
    \caption{Subcaption 1}
  \end{subtable}
  \begin{subtable}[t]{10em}
    \centering
    \exampletable
    \caption{Subcaption 2}
  \end{subtable}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'm not really happy with this solution, as this requires modification to the actual table. Also, I don't think the problem is actually related to using a table. If you do `\captionsetup[subtable]{skip=15pt}`, this will work for Table 1, but not for Table 4.